# How can i set my nav div’s height to be 100% of one it's containing header div?

Tags: css

How can i set my nav div’s height to be 100% of one it's containing header div. As per the CMS I’m using the layout is this.

```
<header>
    <div class=“container”>
        <nav class=“nav-primary collapse navbar-collapse”>
```

Some of these classes come from bootstrap. The header height is set explicitly as 80px. The container div has no height attributes. The nav css has height attribute as auto !important. the CSS is below.

I need the nav to be 100%. I’ve check other posts here on stack overflow but haven’t found anything similar to this situation.

```
html, body {
  height:100%;
}

header {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 999;
  min-height:80px;
```

}

```
.nav-collapse {
    display: block !important; 
    height: auto !important; 
    padding-bottom: 0; 
    overflow: visible !important;
}
```

Comment: Please share a reproducible exmaple on jsfiddle.

Answer (score 0):

You could add this css to your .container:

```
.container {
    position: absolute;
    top:0;
    bottom:0;
    left:0;
    right:0;
}
```

Jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/z4sjjto6/

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% sure without seeing the rest of your HTML/CSS, but you can try this:

```
header .nav-primary {
  height: 100%;
}
```

or

```
.container .nav-primary {
  height: 100%;
}
```

or

```
header .container .nav-primary {
  height: 100%;
}
```